# How dangerous are steroids (injections)?

Tags: testosterone

What are the dangers of steroids (injection/shots) and how can I convince someone to stop using it?

I'm having a hard time at the moment, I try to convince my best friend. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some myths about Steroids like *Taking Any Kind of Steroid Will Result In Death* or *Steroids are Easy to Get*, but they are not true.

> **The Good Side of Steroids?**
>
> Steroids do increase size and strength. In fact, they do so very significantly. In addition to gains in strength and muscle mass they also seem to provide you with more energy and aggressiveness, things that are conducive to good workouts (but not so in interpersonal relationships). Depending on the steroid used, you may also get cell voluminizing effects that promote a bigger pump. Aside from even just the legal risks of steroids, the "good side" comes at a high price.
>
> […]
>
> **Steroid Users Risk:**
>
> 1. Increased Liver Function.
> 2. Depression of Natural Testosterone Production.
> 3. Increase in Cholesterol Levels and Blood Pressure (Not conductive to good cardiovascular health).
> 4. Altered Thyroid Function.
> 5. Headeches.
> 6. Nose bleeds.
> 7. Cramps.
> 8. Development of breastlike tissue in men (Gynecomastia).
> 9. Insulin Insensitivity (Even though Deca Durabolin improves the insulin metabolism).
> 10. Androgenic Side effects such as thinning hair, enlarged prostate, oily skin, water retention, increased body hair, aggressiveness.
> 11. Stunted growth if you are a teenager.
> 12. Oral Steroid specific side effects: In addition to the above, the orals also tend to cause nausea, diarrhea, constipation, and vomiting.
> 13. May accelerate the growth of tumors.

[(Source)](http://bodybuilding.about.com/od/supplementationbasics/a/steroiddangers.htm)

Answer (score -3):

I really don't think steroids for gaining muscles is a good idea. The risks are higher than when you do bodybuilding. I go to the gym a lot and have had a lot of conversations with bodybuilders about the high risk of taking steroids so if you're having steroid injections, please stop. Working out with [dumbbells](http://mybestadjustabledumbbells.com/7-dumbbell-exercises-for-chest/) and other machines is the most natural way to gain muscles.

Comment: Hi and welcome to fitness.stackexchange! Your answer doesn't really adress the question (what are the specific dangers and how to convince someone to stop). If you can add something that the previously accepted answer didn't cover, you should add it to your answer, though.